# An app on my phone has suddenly disappeared but when i look in play store,it is already installed and can be opened

Tags: applications

I just saw that an app which i had on my phone suddenly went missing. I thought I might have uninstalled it by mistake ,but when i looked for it on the play store, it was already installed and i could open it from there. But on my phone it is not there. What can i do.?

Comment: is your phone rooted, or do you use launchers?

Comment: Go to your phone>settings>apps>all apps. is your app there?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using third party launchers like go launcher or apex launcher, it is possible to hide an app and make it invisible in the app drawer. If this is not the case, look for it in the apps section in your settings. Or simply re-install the app from the play store. And turn on "place the app on your home screen" in the play store settings before you reinstall just in case, so that you know the app icon is visible now.